# ATmega: Can one determine if an address is program memory or data memory?

Tags: avr, atmega, memory

On an Atmel ATmega1284 (or any of its AVR cousins), is there any way to determine at compile time or at runtime whether an address that is passed to a function belongs to program memory space or data memory space?

Specifically, I want to provide a debug trace where the input string may be stored in program memory space or in data memory space, but I prefer to use just one function for it so the caller doesn't need to bother: if the input string is stored in program memory, I can copy it to a stack-allocated buffer and then pretend it was always in data memory. For example, in C-like pseudocode:

```
function my_trace(const char *string) {
    if (is_in_program_memory_space(string)) {
        strcpy_P(local_buffer, string);
        print_the_(local_buffer);
    }
    else {
        print_the_(string);
    }
}

const char data_memory_string[] = "data memory string";
const char program_memory_string[] PROGMEM = "program memory string";

my_trace(data_memory_string);
my_trace(program_memory_string);
```

I tried to put in a breakpoint in the compiled code and it seems the addresses of a data-memory–allocated string and a program-memory–allocated string happen to be very close (like 0x800040 versus 0x800360) so I can't rely on address ranges. (And, doing that would probably be unsafe anyway, but that's a different discussion.)

Edit: I'm using the toolchain that comes with Atmel Studio, which in this case is version AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778.

Edit 2: The solution provided by user @NStorm indeed solves the problem. However, on my system it was necessary to typecast the return value of __builtin_avr_flash_segment() to a **signed** char.

Comment: Anything on this hardware that looks like a unified address space is an artificial creation of the toolchain requiring runtime interpretation by software before it can be used by the hardware; as such, this is a question about the behavior not of the chip but of the compiler which could invent any coding scheme it likes; thus this can only be answered in the context of a particular compiler with particular settings.  None has been specified.

Comment: Please refer to my reply to your almost identical comment to one of the answers.

Comment: You still have not identified the compiler you wish to ask about.  People are making guesses, but this site isn't about guessing

Comment: In the answer where someone offered help, I replied that I'm using AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1778.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. If you add new information, please can you edit it into your question rather than post it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the question from different places. Again, welcome, good to have new and competent members.

Comment: @TonyM: Done, and thank you. Hopefully that will prompt some people to be helpful instead of complaining.

Comment: The conditional code in your question is unecessary: if your toolchain has a software-mediated pointer scheme such that memcpy() works for program memory, any print routine taking a pointer-to-terminated-array type input can as well.  You don't need to special case this, because the toolchain already does behind the scenes when it dereferences these artificial pointers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton unfortunately avr-gcc toolchain doesn't handles pointers to a flash memory via it's libc functions like printf(). They have a copy endling with _P for these, like printf_P(), etc. So this still need to be handled manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in other answer, __memx might help. Check it's description:

> This is a 24-bit address space that linearizes flash and RAM: If the high bit of the address is set, data is read from RAM using the lower two bytes as RAM address. If the high bit of the address is clear, data is read from flash with RAMPZ set according to the high byte of the address. See __builtin_avr_flash_segment.

So it's possible to tell where data are stored in FLASH or RAM by checking that high bit. But let's take a look at that __builtin_avr_flash_segment description:

> char __builtin_avr_flash_segment (const __memx void*)

> This built-in takes a byte address to the 24-bit address space __memx and returns the number of the flash segment (the 64 KiB chunk) where the address points to. Counting starts at 0. If the address does not point to flash memory, return -1.

Seems to be just what you need. So basically you can go with this example (taken from [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/853305#comment-853305)):

```
void func (void * dest, const __memx void *source) 
{ 
    if (__builtin_avr_flash_segment (source) < 0)
        strcpy (dest, source);
    else
        strcpy_P (dest, source);
}
```

PS. I suggest to read whole [Named Address Spaces manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html). It has some caveats and limatitions.

Comment: Looks like I'm out of luck then, because Atmel's current AVR-GCC doesn't seem to support __builtin_avr_flash_segment. I guess I'll have to build the toolchain myself.

Comment: @OleWolf which one do you call "current"? Atmel no longer exists, it was purchased by Microchip. I have `avr-gcc (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1759) 5.4.0` from the official Microchip bundle and it's compiled this example with __builtin_avr_flash_segment() just perfectly fine.

Comment: I was of course referring to the Atmel Studio (provided by Microchip, yes) that I downloaded only a few weeks ago. My toolchain is version 3.6.2_1778. I seem to have jumped to a conclusion though, but the function doesn't seem to work as documented: the compiler states that __builtin_avr_flash_segment(address) < 0 is always false.

Comment: @OleWolf you have to provide a correct pointer with a __memx attribue for it to work. Probably you are calling it with __flash type pointer argument instead?

Comment: I think I do. "const __memx char some_format[] = "foo"; (in the global scope) that I pass to the function "foo(const __memx char *format)" in which I call "(__builtin_avr_flash_segment(format) < 0)" causes the compiler to complain that "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]".

Comment: @OleWolf __memx just linearizes the RAM & FLASH. But strangely my compiler doesn't complains on that even if I initialize variable as __memx too. Can you try to initialize it as `const __flash char format` and then call it with a cast like `foo((const __memx char *)format);`?

Comment: Same result, but that makes sense to me. The compiler doesn't seem to be complaining about the parameter but about comparing __builtin_avr_flash_segment(...) with 0.

Comment: @OleWolf I've just compiled and disassembled example (with avr-objdump). str1 are const __flash type, str2 are casual string in RAM. Disassembly shows it works like intended. See this listing screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/qzjZgev.png. When it's calling a function from main(), it loads 3 bytes (as __memx are 24-bit pointer) into registers where r22 stores MSB. As you can see it loads 0 for flash string there and 0x80 (1 in MSB) for RAM string. Later, __builtin...() checks that bit and jumps to appropriate function as expected.

Comment: I tried with another version of the toolchain at my customer's site and got the same compiler complaint. However, it seems that a char is treated as an unsigned type. Typecasting the return value of __builtin_avr_flash_segment() to a signed char yields -1 for non-flash memory. And, now it works. :)

Comment: @OleWolf, that's good to hear but the solution is buried away in your comment. Please can you either accept an answer or, if not are the answer, edit your question with a footnote explaining your solution. Otherwise its lost for readers with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your AVR GCC is recent enough you could use `__memx` address space, see [Named Address Spaces](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html) in the GCC docu.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting this right, but how does that solve the problem of determining which address space a parameter was stored in?

Comment: @OleWolf the hardware doesn't _have_ a unified address space, so one would be a software construct to begin with.  Tell the toolchain to use this, and all references to the objects will get generated, evaluated, etc using this numeric coding scheme.  You're not looking at direct register/memory operations, but rather ones that have to go through generated code.  Perhaps this may suggest that your goal arrises from a misunderstanding of the interaction between the toolchain and this Harvard architecture.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm fully aware of the difference between von Neumann and Harvard memory architectures. That's why I asked whether there was some compiler-provided support for determining which of the address spaces some address belongs to.

(My addemdum that I might be able to derive a hint by looking at the address nonetheless came from the fact that although the address spaces are independent I might have been lucky to learn that the address spaces don't overlap. Regrettably, they seem to do.)

Comment: @OleWolf - again, there simply is no unified address space.  So any construct which creates one necessarily involves a number scheme that cannot directly be used by the hardware, but has to first be interpreted by software at each attempted access.  You're asking how to untangle a confusion which could only even be a situation of ambiguity in the context of a software environment which simulated a unified address space by tying together two entirely distinct hardware address spaces requiring distinct instructions to access.  Only in the context of such is an ambiguous pointer even possible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I know that there's no unified address space on a Harvard architecture, and that you can't compare an address in one address space with the address of another, thank you very much. Please acknowledge that I was asking if the compiler provides any help, because at least the toolchain knows. But, one may find that on some Harvard architecture, the address spaces nonetheless have different addresses and thus could be identifiable--even if this is an unsafe approach, like I said originally.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the *sparse population* of actual items *within* an address space with the concept of an address space itself, and also that of Van Neumann architectures with Harvard-like optimized paths (eg, essentially any modern CPU) for actual Harvard architectures.  Likely you're not going to get beyond the present compiler-mediated view unless you sit down and spend some time studying the actual architecture manual and the specific opcodes available.

Comment: No, Chris, I'm not confusing anything. Please understand that I'm asking whether the TOOLCHAIN can help discern whether an address belongs to one or the other in a function call, either at compile time or (much less likely) at runtime. (I'm beginning to regret even mentioning that on some processors, one might derive a clue by looking at the address ranges, although it's trivial to understand that Harvard architectures, too, can place data and memory in different address ranges, even if they exist in different and indepenedent address spaces.)

Comment: @ChrisStratton it's not about the architecture. It's about how C Compiler handles this. As avr-gcc has helper macros to store data in flash space and access it, such as __flash attribute but OP was asking if there is a way later to check if the passed pointer to a data are *supposed* (by the compiler, as it knows how the variable was initialized) to point to a flash or ram space.

Comment: Your "no" comment is baseless, that this is a feature of the toolchain and not the hardware is exactly the point I've made repeatedly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are right. But how does that comment relates to OP question where he was clearly asking about the "feature of the toolchain" and not the hardware architecture?

Comment: @NStorm the OP's initial comment to this answer seemed to reject this.  It's still really not clear that they fundamentally grasp that the only way such a confusion can result, is in a software scheme which supports one sort of pointer which can target either address space - this is actually an XY problem, the conditional code they propose in the question isn't even needed, if the pointer is valid (due to runtime interpretation by behind the scenes toolchain code) then it works with printf() and not just memcpy().

Comment: @ChrisStratton as noted in my other recent comment while avr-gcc toolchain can handle those pointers in compiled code, it's still not handled by libc functions which are pre-compiled and has 2 versions for RAM & FLASH and should be handled manually. I assume that is the source of OP question.